# NaN while create Pandas DataFrame from nested dictionary using single element tuple as dict keys

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a question related to Pandas DataFrame created from a nested dictionary.

I have noticed that when I create a dataframe using the following dict, the cells are all NaN

```
dict1 = {
   0: {('kfield',): 100.0},
   1: {('kfield',): 101.0},
   2: {('kfield',): 102.5},
   3: {('kfield',): 103.5},
   4: {('kfield',): 104.5},
   5: {('kfield',): 105.5}
}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict1)
print df
```

Result

```
         0   1   2   3   4   5
kfield NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

However, when the inner dictionary key consists of a tuple with more than one values, the dataframe is created with proper values.

```
dict2 = {
   0: {('kfield','kfield2',): 100.0},
   1: {('kfield','kfield2',): 101.0},
   2: {('kfield','kfield2',): 102.5},
   3: {('kfield','kfield2',): 103.5},
   4: {('kfield','kfield2',): 104.5},
   5: {('kfield','kfield2',): 105.5}
}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict2)
print df2
```

Result

```
                    0      1      2      3      4      5
kfield kfield2  100.0  101.0  102.5  103.5  104.5  105.5
```

Not sure why Pandas behaves like this. Am I missing something?

I am using Pandas version '0.19.2'

Comment: Which pandas version are you using? Both approaches work fine with the latest version. Also its better to upgrade to python 3.

Comment: Thanks @Dark. I confirmed that with python3 and v0.22 I am getting the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this bug has to do with older Pandas version. I have verified that the code works as expected with Python3 and Pandas v0.22.0

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the last ',' from tuple in 'dict1' dictionary then its working as you expected. Providing code for the same.

```
import pandas as pd

dict1 = {
   0: {('kfield'): 100.0},
   1: {('kfield'): 101.0},
   2: {('kfield'): 102.5},
}

dict2 = {
   0: {('kfield','kfield2',): 100.0},
   1: {('kfield','kfield2',): 101.0},
   2: {('kfield','kfield2',): 102.5},
}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict2)
df = pd.DataFrame(dict1)

print df
print df2

Output:
            0      1      2
kfield  100.0  101.0  102.5
                    0      1      2
kfield kfield2  100.0  101.0  102.5
```

Comment: Telgore - The keys for the inner dictionary are computed, It can be single element tuple, so I can't change the representation. I was wondering the cause of this issue. Based on the fact that the latest version of the code doesn't have this problem, I am guessing Pandas maintainers have fixed the underlying issue.